# UPDATE Statement NULLS

Tags: sql, excel, vba

When running an update statement from VBA/SQL to SQL server, the result looks like below..

```
plant   taskno  tskstatus       opened  openedby      title closed  closedby
UK      1       closed          DCR     2014-09-01   1      NULL    NULL
```

The update statement moves tskstatus from OPEN to CLOSED.

The closed and closedby should = to TODAYS DATE and MYNAME

However, the values are not changing from NULL.

Can anyone explain what I would need to do to change this?

Code is below..(I know there are more COLLUMNS in the code, I removed some to make the text more readable)

```
sSqlClose = "UPDATE [header] SET tskstatus = 'closed' WHERE opened = '" & ValueID & "'"
sSqlClose2 = "UPDATE [header] SET closedby = 'MYNAME' WHERE 'NULL' = '" & ValueID & "'"
sSqlClose3 = "UPDATE [header] SET closed = 'CLOSED' WHERE 'NULL' = '" & ValueID & "'"

SQLconn.Execute sSqlClose
SQLconn.Execute sSqlClose2
SQLconn.Execute sSqlClose3
```

Thanks

Comment: What is ValueId, and why are you matching it against three things? Also, I suspect you are setting ALL tasks to closed that are opened now. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
SET closed = 'NULL'
```

Try:

```
SET closed = NULL
```

And you can update multiple columns in a single statement:

```
update  header
set     tskstatus = 'mission accomplished'
,       closedby = 'gwbush'
,       closed = 'closed'
where   IssueID = 'WAR-ON-TERROR-12'
```

Comment: No joy, still putting a NULL in

Comment: `WHERE 'NULL' = '" & ValueID & "'"` is also unlikely to match any row ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the problem, but could you simply not do something like this in one statement?

```
update header
   set tskstatus = 'closed'
      ,closed    = current_date
      ,closedby  = 'yourname'
 where tskstatus = 'open'
   and opened    = ?
```

Comment: Currently tskstatus= Open Closed= NULL  Closedby= NULL....when I run the update it changes to...tskstatus=Closed Closed=NULL Closedby=NULL....I need it to be tskstatus=Closed Closed=TODAY Closedby=ME  For some reason the NULL values are not changing? I tried the above with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Working on the assumption you do not want to close ALL opened tasks at once, but only one specific one, and that `ValueId' contains your TASKNUMBER, this should work:

```
sSqlClose = "UPDATE [header] SET tskstatus = 'closed', closed = 'foo', closedby = 'bar'  WHERE taskno = '" & ValueID & "'"
```

All in one statement.

If any of my assumptions are wrong, this won't work. But then you should give more information :)